# Recursive Division Maze Java

Tags: java, algorithm, maze

I'm having problems with completing the algorithm based on [this link](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/1/12/maze-generation-recursive-division-algorithm). 
After building a wall I choose the upper or left part of the maze and it seems to create itself only to the point where it needs to break the recursion and enter another *divide* method call. I'm not sure if I understand the values needed to be passed to the last call of the *divide* method correctly.

```
    public void divide(int x, int y, int width, int hight) {
        if (width< 2 || hight< 2) ;  

        else {
            boolean horizontal = chooseOrientation(width,hight);

            if (horizontal) {
                int randomNumber = r.nextInt(hight - 1);
                wallY = randomNumber + y;

                for (int i = x; i < width; i++) {                       
                    fields[wallY][i].setHorizontalWall();
                }
                fields[wallY][r.nextInt(width- 1)].deleteHorizontalWall();   
                hight = wallY - y + 1;
                divide(x, y, width, hight);
            }

            else {
                int randomNumber = r.nextInt(width- 1);
                WallX = randomNumber + x;

                for (int i = y; i < hight; i++) {
                    fields[i][WallX].setVerticalWall();
                }
                fields[r.nextInt(hight - 1) + y][WallX].deleteVerticalWall();
                width = WallX - x + 1;
               }

            if(horizontal){
                hight = y + hight + WallY-1;
                y = WallY + 1;
            }
            else {
                width = WallX - 1 + width + x;
                x = WallX + 1;
            }
            divide(x, y, width, hight);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the "recursive-division" algorithm you start with a full 2-dimensional grid graph and you then start removing edges (= building "walls") alternating in horizontal and vertical "stripes". In every "stripe" only a single edge ("door") is left.

A graph-based version of this algorithm can be found here:

https://github.com/armin-reichert/mazes

https://github.com/armin-reichert/mazes/blob/master/mazes-algorithms/src/main/java/de/amr/maze/alg/others/RecursiveDivision.java

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the answer because it will resolve someone's else problem ASAP.